# Which of the following methods will be legal in the subclass?

Tags: java, methods, arguments, return-value, subclass

I am confused about how to create methods in a subclass. I am hitting my head against a brick wall with this and not even sure how to word the question.

```
import java.io.*;
public class A {
   public double method1(double x, double y) { return 1.0;  }
}
class B extends A {
   //subclass method to be placed after this line

}
```

---

1. `public double method1(double x, double y) { ... }`
2. `public int method1(double x, double y) { ... }`
3. `public double method1(int x, int y) { .... }`
4. `public int method1(double x, double y, double z) { ... }`

Which of the following methods will be legal in the subclass and why?

Comment: Try them all and you'll know :)

Comment: I'm not expert too. I'm just suggesting you to try it. I'm friendly, didn't you see the smile I put there? Here is another one :D

Comment: You can't do that, I'll shoot you.

Comment: WOW.. That worked.. I feel Chuck Norris.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Overrides method1 with new functionality.
2. Illegal because it has the same parameter signature but a different return type.

3,4. legal but are really separate methods.

Just consider the argument types to be part of the method name:

- Only if the name plus the argument types fully match, you override the same method with new functionality. In this case, the return type must match (starting with Java 1.5, the return type may be specialized in subclasses, see https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/covariant_return_types_in_java)
- In other cases, the added methods are just separate methods with the same name. Java statically picks the right one for each invocation at compile time based on the provided argument types. If arguments are compatible and the names are the same for multiple methods, it picks the closest match.

Comment: i think return type can be covarient also according to scjp

Answer (score 2):

If you put the following methods in class, as per my understanding, this should happen:

```
public double method1(double x, double y) { ... }
```

This is overridden method, which means you overriding the behavior of method1 in your subclass, which is perfectly legal.

```
public int method1(double x, double y) { ... }
```

Compilation error: This is a try to do method overloading but not in a legal way. Method overloading allows to have same method name but different type/number of arguments. Method overloading is done with different parameter list but NOT by using a different return type.

```
public double method1(int x, int y) { .... }
```

This one is a legal overloaded method

```
public int method1(double x, double y, double z) { ... }
```

Again a legal overloaded method

Answer (score 2):

1. Overrides the method in A and is legal
2. Is illegal because returntype is different and not a specialisation of the returntype of the method in A
3. Is an overloaded method because the argument types are different
4. Is an overloaded method because there are more parameters

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding

Comment: @Skippy But it has more parameters, Java won't be confused which one you want.. It'll know because of the number of parameters.

Comment: Yes. But in general, only the parameters are considered when comparing  methodnames for overloading or overriding. But with overriding a method the returntype must be the same or a more specific implementation if the parameters are the same. 4 is an overloaded method because the name is the same but it has different parameters, so the returntype is not important.

Answer (score 2):

1. Legal overriding
2. Not Legal overriding because return type should be covarient or same
3. legal overloading
4. legal overloading

overriding rules :- * parameter must same

- return type must same or it should be covarient
- exception if it is checked it should be sub class of that overridden method
- access modifier should be same or less restricted

overloading rules :- * parameter must different

- return type can be same
- access modifier can be same

Read Katherine Sierra, Bert Bates (SCJP Book) for full rules or Java doc